# Rumplestiltskin: The Dwarf with a Bad Rap

Tags: shrek-forever-after, grimms-fairy-tales

Rumplestiltskin played a major role in making the daughter of a miller become a queen, by spinning the straw into gold for the king. The first time, the miller's daughter gave him her necklace in return. The second time, the maid gives Rumplestiltskin her ring. The third time, Rumplestiltskin asks for their firstborn. If Rumplestiltskin helped the maid become a queen, then why is he considered bad in the fairy tale, as well as in Shrek Forever After?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but considered by whom? Surely it's down to individual writers to make characters good or bad as they see fit (e.g. the Big Bad Wolf is portrayed as a good character in Shrek and Red Riding Hood is bad in Shrek 3)

Comment: @Questioner   Because the deal is human trafficing.  Making such a deal implies that the firstborn is not a person but an item of property, a slave of the mother which she has the right to sell, and Rumplestiltskin had the right to bargin for.  If the kingdom has standard medieval inheiritance laws, the firstborn son (of the king) would be the heir to the throne, and even the firstborn daughter (of the king) would have a chance of becoming queen regnant if she didn't have any brothers.  Continued:

Comment: @Questioner   If the king dies without any surviving children, the kingdom might suffer civil war between rival claimants.  Think of what happened to England in 1066 when King Edward died and his closest relative was a young grandnephew Edgar the Aetheling (c. 1051-c.1126).  So if they made the deal while hoping she would become queen, the miller's daughter and Rumplestiltskin would be committing treason against the kingdom by reducing theprobability that the kng would have a surviving child, as well as ignoring the right of the king to keep his children.  Continued.

Comment: @Questioner   And if a child of the King just magically disappeared the new queen could be in big trouble, And if her story was believed she might be divorced and imprisoned or executed for making such a disloyal deal.  So Rumplestiltskin was being very harsh to the miller's daughter by demanding her firstborn.  And what did Rumplestiltskin what the baby for?  To be his child, or his slave, or his dinner?

Answer (score 2):

Because, as ever with these stories, he tried to claim the firstborn child as his final reward from the deal.

That is, after all, the deal the girl had agreed to in exchange for spinning the straw. Claiming the firstborn is a standard 'evil' trope, and doing such a deal with someone in danger of their life isn't exactly positive behaviour.

Comment: Okay. Sorry this question is closed, and thanks for the answer.